# Why is "Hello".foldLeft(1)(_.toLong * _.toLong) an error?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and a bit perplexed. While going through "Scala for the Impatient," and doing the exercises, I tried one where the result is the product of all the numeric values of the string "Hello". My first thought was to do the following:

```
"Hello".foldLeft(1)(_.toLong * _.toLong)
```

However, the expression (_.toLong * _.toLong) results in a type mismatch between the operator and the operand, an Int was expected, but it received a Long.

The following works, though:

```
"Hello".map(_.toLong).reduce(_ * _)
```

Why does the operator '*' expect an Int instead of a Long when using foldLeft? Is it because of the list's contents? Are the characters implicitly converted to Ints?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it because your initial argument, `1`, has type `int`? What happens if you change it to `1L` (or the Scala equivalent)? (Posting as a comment rather than an answer because I don't know Scala, so this is just an educated guess.)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Good call.

Comment: So you mean Scala's * operator cannot multiply an Int by a Long? Wow, that is progress ...

Comment: @Kaz: No - `1l * 1` and `1 * 1l` work just fine. The problem is that since `foldLeft`'s seed is `Int`, it expects the function passed to it to return `Int` as well.

Comment: @IdanArye Eek! How the heck do you fold-multiply over a list that contains a complex number, real, rational, and integer?

Comment: @Kaz: Since Scala is statically typed, you can't really have such a list - all the numbers will be casted to the larges type. Writing `Seq(1,2l,3.0)`, for example, yields `Seq[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Promoting my comment to an answer so the question can be closed.)

This is because your initial argument, `1`, has type `Int`. You can resolve this by changing it to `1L`.